# Kubuntu -- text snippets or clipboard manager with sticky (static) items

Tags: kde, text, clipboard-manager

I am currently using the default clipboard manager of Kubuntu 19.10, I believe it is called Klipper.

AFAIK it does not support sticky (static) items.
I installed Clipit from the Software center but it doesn't seem to run on KDE desktop.

What's a way to have a few simple text snippets readily available on Kubuntu for copy-and-paste jobs?

Comment: "Best" requires an opinion, and we don't engage in opinion discussions here as per http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic . May I suggest you visit http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com if you don't find what you want at https://store.kde.org/ ?

Comment: Thanks I changed the inappropriate wording of the question. Maybe the down-vote could be removed?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I am not really looking for a text expander or autokey kind of function. I am looking for a replacement for the static items function I am used to with ClipIt.

Comment: I tried it out this morning, installed from the repo, but I couldn't get it to behave properly on Kubuntu. Maybe I need to download a newer version from the dev's site?

Comment: Downloaded and installed latest version of copyq. It just doesn't work on my system.

Comment: I don't mean to push things too far but what exact problems do you face using Kubuntu's built-in clipboard? What do you want to do that you can't? And maybe expand on what exactly you mean by "support sticky (static) items".

Comment: @DKBose With the built-in clipboard I see a list of what I copied, in chronological order. If I want to re-use an important telephone number or terminal command, I need to look through dozens of entries, and it might not even be there anymore. But static items in ClipIt makes my important stuff always readily accessible.

Comment: There's a search bar at the top. That should help. It even finds internal strings: typing `tac` will find `detach`, etc. As for items not being there anymore, that would be a function of how many entries you permit. As I mentioned previously, if I'm sure I'll be needing a particular snippet repeatedly, I'd store them using texpander or rofi. Anyway, I think I understand your point. I'll check if it's possible with `copyq` (which works for me in Kubuntu 18.04 and 20.04).

Comment: @DKBose My bad, CopyQ works. It is in the system tray, and  Kubuntu in its great wisdom decided that it should be hidden by default. But I found it. :) And the "pinned items" function seems to work, which satisfies my needs. So you could write CopyQ as an answer.

Comment: Please go ahead and post an answer yourself and ping me when you've done so. I've been looking at `copyq` and it seems to have a large following. Plus, the dev seems quite active and responsive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104437/discussion-between-shmu-and-dk-bose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a clipboard manager called `copyq` that is in the Software Center, and it supports "pinned" items. It does the job.

Install it from the Software Center, and you are almost ready to go.

When it launches, it puts an icon in the system tray, but by default, the icon is hidden. So if you want to see it displayed:

1. Right-click on system tray
2. Select `Configure System Tray`
3. Go to the `Entries` tab
4. In the `Visibility` column, select `Shown`

If you want it to autostart, you can configure that in the copyq `Preferences`.

Alternatively, the default clipboard manager can be used for basic clipboard memory, and `Gnome To Do` (available in Software Center) can be used for long-term storage of text snippets. `Gnome To Do`is not designed for that purpose, but it could be used for it.